# Simple Question: Cannot Find Symbol - Class in Java from CMD

Tags: java, cmd, compilation

Tried looking into other questions or in tutorials, it seems to be a common problem for beguiners, but I am unable to understand what to do, and would like someone help me in a step by step how can I make my code to work.

From IntelliJ when pressing the run button it works fine, but when doing it through the windows terminal it throws:

```
Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Run.main();
        ^
  symbol:   variable Run
  location: class Main
1 error
error: compilation failed
```

Here is the code:

Main.java

```
package com.test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Run.main();
    }
}
```

Run.java

```
package com.test;

public class Run {
    public static void main() {
        System.out.println("[-] Bad Usage");
   }
}
```

The path for the project is: `C:\Users\isaac\IdeaProjects\ex1\src\com\test`

What I already tried:
`javac Main.java Run.java` (from test, com, src or ex1 folder) - Maybe I did it in the wrong way.

I think that was the solutions I found, but every-time I do the javac it throws the same error...

Comment: Because the Run class is defined in a different package, you need to do 'import com.hadassah;'

Comment: sorry was my mistake, both are package.test. Just copy pasted for this example and forgot to change both from hadassah to test...so I still have the problem.

Comment: Then make sure that you compile them at the same time with *.java or that you compile the Run class first.

Comment: You mean I should do javac *.java? I just did, didn't work. And doing the Run first also doesn't work. Besides, sometimes when I run the javac it creates a new file called Main.class or Run.class, not sure for what...

Comment: javac Run.java Main.java or javac *.java or javac src\com\test\Run.java src\com\test\Main.java or javac src\com\test\ *.java